# Call not audible via flowroute with asterisk

Tags: asterisk, voip, gsm, flow-router

I have configured asterisk with flowroute. The registration is successful and outbound call connects but i am unable to hear any sound. My configurations are as follow

sip.conf

```
[general]
register => username:password@sip.flowroute.com
allow=ulaw
```

sip-custom-contexts.conf

```
[flowroute]                     ; keep this lowercase, do not change format
type=friend
secret=username
username=password
host=sip.flowroute.com
type=peer
transport=udp
port=5060
dtmfmode=rfc2833
context=to-pstn                ; change to 'ext-did' or 'from-trunk' for asterisk@home
canreinvite=no
allow=ulaw
;allow=g729                     ;uncomment this line if you have G.729 licenses installed.
insecure=port,invite
fromdomain=sip.flowroute.com
keepalive=yes
qualify=no
progressinband=yes
```

rtp.conf

```
[general]
rtpstart=10000
rtpend=2000
```

Kindly guide in this regard

Comment: Also, remove your SIP credentials from this post and change them in provider's portal. Anyone can use them...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved by changing codec. After changing

```
allow=ulaw
```

to

```
allow=all
```

The call was working fine, with audible voice.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your nat and external ip settings.

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+SIP+NAT+solutions

Comment: If there was NAT issue then why call connects? How audio issue is related with NAT?

Comment: I added the required NAT configurations but no progress. asterisk debug logs shows following : Failed to get 160 samples from write factory 0x7fd93000c2c8

Comment: It is rtp issue. You have not forwarded rtp ports or asterisk think it on other ip and advertise that ip.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest reaching out to Flowroute's support for help on this. And I'd like to second advice from lvl to get those SIP credentials removed for your own account security.